# Inverse of a matrix with outer product

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I need to take inverse of this matrix:

\begin{equation}
i \mathbf{I}_8-\begin{pmatrix}
(a+ib-c)\sigma\otimes\sigma & a \sigma\otimes\sigma \\
a \sigma\otimes\sigma & (a-ib-c) \sigma\otimes\sigma
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Here $\mathbf{I}_8$ is $8*8$ identity matrix and, $\sigma$ is Pauli matrix such that $\sigma\otimes\sigma= \sum_{i=1}^3 \sigma^i\otimes \sigma^i=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 2 & 0 \\
 0 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$.

I would like to have the final result in terms of $\sigma\otimes\sigma$ and Identity matrix. I tried brute force inverse of the resulting $8*8$ matrix but that way I could not write the final result in terms of $\sigma\otimes\sigma$. I was wondering if there are any identities that can help me simplfy this calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the properties of the Schur complement

\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{matrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{matrix}\right)^{-1} = \left(\begin{matrix} A^{-1} + A^{-1} B S^{-1} C A^{-1} & -A^{-1} B S^{-1} \\ -S^{-1} C A^{-1} & S^{-1} \end{matrix}\right)= 
\left(\begin{matrix} I_n & -A^{-1} B \\ 0 & I_m \end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix} A^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & S^{-1} \end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix} I_n & 0 \\ -C A^{-1} & I_m \end{matrix}\right),
\end{equation}

with the Schur matrix

\begin{equation}
S = D - C A^{-1} B
\end{equation}

and the inverse of an outer product

\begin{equation}
(E \otimes F)^{-1} = E^{-1} \otimes F^{-1}.
\end{equation}

Note that you still have to invert the submatrices $A, B, C, D$.

Regards

Comment: Thank you. This looks like a way to go. But I do not think that $S^{-1}=D^{-1}-B^{-1}AC^{-1}$ is correct.

Comment: I used the property $\left( \hat{A} \cdot \hat{B} \right)^{-1} = \hat{B}^{-1} \cdot \hat{A}^{-1}$ twice.

Comment: But you have $(A-B)$ kind of matrix in definition of S. Isn't it? And $(A-B)^{-1}\neq A^{-1}-B^{-1}$.

Comment: Ok i see, i will remove this mistake.